# Dojo Dgrid - Events in Configuration

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I've been looking into `dgrid` and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to attach an event to a `grid` that uses `dojo/on` without explicitly calling `grid.on` but, instead, passes it as a method (or set of methods) in the initial configuration of the grid. The reason for this is because the grid instance itself out of scope upon creation and I can't find any documentation on it.

So, instead of

```
var grid = new (declare[Grid])({}, element);
grid.on('.dgrid-row:click', function(){console.log('Hello World!')});
```

having something like

```
var grid = new (declare[Grid])({
    'events' : {
        '.dgrid-row:click' : function(){console.log('Hello World!')}
    }
}, element);
```

Ideas? Alternatives?

Comment: Can you expand on the problem you are trying to solve?  I don't understand how the second example is functionally different than the first.

Comment: It's been so long since I looked at this question so I can't fully remember the context but I believe that, at the time, I was dealing with a library that allowed me to pass in configuration options and set up the grid for me but didn't return the grid object itself. You are right, though, the two are functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the the DijitRegistry extension, which will allow you to get a reference to your grid like you would with a normal dijit widget, through registry.byId... then you can use grid.on, as usual.

Example : https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/DijitRegistry